# In zsh, what is the difference between (${(@s.\n.)s}) & (${(@s/\n/)s})

Tags: zsh, array

In zsh, what is the difference between `(${(@s.\n.)s})` (dots) & `(${(@s/\n/)s})` (slashes), e.g., in:

```bsh
s=a\\nb\\nc\\nd

a=(${(@s.\n.)s})
b=(${(@s/\n/)s})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The character, whatever character you use, delimits the string that you want to split the variable's value on.

The `zsh` manual, for example, uses `.` to delimit the string in an example, while the subsection heading uses `:`:

> `s:string:`
>
> Force field splitting at the separator string.  Note that a
>          string of two or more characters means that all of them must
>          match in sequence; this differs from the treatment of two or
>          more characters in the `IFS` parameter. [...]
>
> [...]; hence the following:
>
> ```
>   line="one::three"
>   print -l "${(s.:.)line}"
> ```
>
> produces two lines of output for one and three and elides the
>   empty field.  To override this behaviour, supply the `(@)` flag
>   as well, i.e.  `${(@s.:.)line}`.

At the start of that section in the manual, the fact that the delimiter character may be any character is mentioned. It is also mentioned that you may use `[` and `]` together, as well as matching pairs of other types of brackets (my emphasis):

> The following flags (except `p`) are followed by one or more arguments as
>   shown.  **Any character**, or the matching pairs `(...)`, `{...}`, `[...]`,
>   or `<...>`, may be used in place of a colon as delimiters, but note
>   that when a flag takes more than one argument, a matched pair of
>   delimiters must surround each argument.

Comment: What delimiters are most commonly used?  I'd prefer to make my scripts easily digestible

Comment: @XDR I would probably personally use `:`, unless the string delimited contains colons. In the end, being _consistent_ is what's most important.